# Session Cookie - Magento login not working if the Shop is at the root domain

Tags: magento, session, cookies, authentication

I had a strange Problem.
After transferring a shop to the live domain `xyz.tld`, users and Admins couldn't login.

The cookie domain was set to `.xyz.tld` (or `xyz.tld`) without difference.

Not setting the cookie domain allows to login, but this leads to the problem that sometimes two cookies with the same name and different subdomain are stored.

Also, without cookie domain, login in Safari is not possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a check for cookies from a parent domain in magento.
If the shop is at your root domain (2nd level domain) and the cookie domain is set to the same, magento always believes every cookie is from a parent domain and deletes every session right after creating it.

The fix is easy!

In the File `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php` find:

```
            // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
            if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 0) {
                $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
            }
```

and replace it with:

```
            // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
            if (strpos($currentCookieDomain, $host) > 1) {
                $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName(), null, $host);
            }
```

This won't create any new problems, because no subdomain exists that is one char longer than the domain. Every subdomain must at least include one letter and the dot to separate it from the domain. The only thing that is one char longer than `xyz.tld` is either a different domain, or `.xyz.tld`.

I opened [Magento Issue #7015](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/591) for this bug, so this should be fixed in an upcoming version!

update: The bug is still open (02/2016). Someone posted a different fix in the comments to the bug report, you might want to check it out too: https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/14f49b6ddcb69640d697